# iptables - What does the range in bracket mean?

Tags: linux, firewall, iptables, redhat

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Don’t understand [0:0] iptable syntax](https://serverfault.com/questions/373871/dont-understand-00-iptable-syntax)

My server is Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.

I'm not an expert in Linux iptables firewall.  I've the following entries in iptables:

```
[root@myserver ~]# more /etc/sysconfig/iptables
# Generated by iptables-save v1.3.5 on Mon Sep 14 20:04:30 2009
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [10934:1556118]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [111392:6686084]
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 5050
-A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
-A OUTPUT -d 192.168.0.200 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.200:5050
-A OUTPUT -d 127.0.0.1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:5050
COMMIT
# Completed on Mon Sep 14 20:04:30 2009
```

What does the value range in the bracket mean?  For example, here: `PREROUTING ACCEPT [10934:1556118]`, what does the range 10934:1556118 mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is packet and  byte counters, try this:

```
iptables -nvL OUTPUT
```

PREROUTING

> Address translation occurs before
>   routing. Facilitates the
>   transformation of the destination IP
>   address to be compatible with the
>   firewall's routing table. Used with
>   NAT of the destination IP address,
>   also known as destination NAT or DNAT.

Comment: Thanks for that information.  On executing `iptables -nvL OUTPUT`, I'm getting pkts value as 7984K and bytes value as 2310M.  But the values in `/etc/sysconfig/iptables` are showing the same values.  Why this difference?

Comment: @Gnanam could you post the top line showing the packts information...

Comment: `Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
7984K 2310M ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0`

Comment: try this for a simple test, `iptables-save > /tmp/test.iptables` then `cat /tmp/test.iptables | grep "OUTPUT ACCEPT"`, those are just counters and you can even reset it with the option -Z if you want. `iptables -Z`; `iptables -Z -t mangle`; `iptables -Z -t nat`

Answer (score 3):

They are the saved values of the byte and packet counters for the specified table's chain policy. In your case the nat table. Have a look [**here**](http://www.faqs.org/docs/iptables/iptables-save.html) for more information on iptables-save.