# Don't understand [0:0] iptable syntax

Tags: iptables

I'm struggling with some `iptables` rules. I'm a newbie in `iptables`. I found some resources where I get the following command related to `iptables`. This is stored in a file that will be executed.

`[0:0] -A PREROUTING -s 10.1.0.0/24 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 81 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.1.0.6:3128`

Can anybody explain me what does [0:0] mean? Also, some link related to this in `iptables` are welcome.

Thanks in advance!

P.S. If you need more rules, just let me know.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The [0:0] or [1280:144299] or whatever are the count of [`Packets`:`Bytes`] that have been trough the chain . They are saved when you run an `iptables-save` command and are used by the `iptables-restore` command to initialise the counters.

---

The `Packets` and `bytes` values can be useful *for some statistical purposes. Issuing an iptables-save command with the -c argument would then make it possible for us to reboot without breaking our statistical and accounting routines.* (Quoted from *Iptables Tutorial 1.2.2* - by Oskar Andreasson)
Conclusively, restoring the `iptables` rules with `Packets` and `bytes` specified will not affect the rule behavior, just will keep a "stateful" track of `Packets` respectively `bytes` that match the rule.

Comment: What if I save my rules with those specified. Does it influence the networking? If yes, how.

Answer (score 8):

Every rule has two counters; the number of packets and the number of bytes that have matched each rule.  The default policies also have counters.

This syntax goes in the input to `iptables-restore` and sets the counters to whatever number is in the square brackets.  `iptables-save` puts the current value of the counters into the square brackets in its output.

You can see human-readable counts for each rule using:

```
iptables -L -n -v
```

and the raw values with

```
iptables -L -n -v -x
```